# Flask login authentication lost after redirect in Safari

Tags: safari, flask-login

User logging-in, is OK in Chrome and Safari (e.g. current_user.is_authenticated is true in both browsers)

After logging-in, the user is redirected to another page.
The authentication is still ok in Chrome, but **not ok in Safari (current_user.is_authenticated is False)**.

What could be the difference?
Thanks,
Avner

---

flask --version
Flask 1.0.2
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jul  8 2017, 05:00:20) 
[GCC 4.9.2]

Macbook 10.13.6
Safari 11.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after I upgraded Safari from 11.1.2 to 13.0.3, and kicked the Safari browser 
(e.g. cleared the cache in web inspector, closed and restarted the browser, closed, and reopened the tab in incognito mode)